# Prado & NetBeans

Tags: php, ide, ubuntu, prado

I have Ubuntu with NetBeans, and use it for PHP/Prado development. I installed NB because it supposedly supports Prado. To my disappointment, it seems that Prado plugin work only for older versions of NB.

I tried to install the plugin, but with no success. Does anyone have NB 6.9 with Prado support?

If not, I'm wondering which IDE to use for Prado under Ubuntu. I know that phpEdit works well, but it's a windows app. I'm even thinking of running it with wine :S.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/the_first_alpha_version_of

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that's only good for older versions. I downloaded prado plugin from their site, and it generated errors.

Comment: BTW, it turned out that it has prado support anyway. Maybe automatically added ?